# Add ids as an array to hidden field on onclick function

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, arrays

I have 2 tables: Products and Services. I have added products and services to cart functions as rows.

So on each click on trash image, I need to pass as an product and service ids as an array.

```
<% @service_appointment_operation.each do |sao| %>
          <tr  style="color: #e06d6d;" data-tt-parent-id="ser_<%= @service_appointment.id %>" data-tt-id="ser_<%= @service_appointment.id %>_<%= sao.operation.id %>">
            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" onclick="deleteRow(<%=service_appointment.id%>,'<%= sao.operation_type %>')"></span></td>
          </tr>
          <% end %>
```

JavaScript function:

```js
function deleteRow(id,type) {
  var operation_type = type;
  if (operation_type == "Service") {
    $('#deleted_service_ids').val(id);
  } else {
    $('#deleted_product_ids').val(id);
  }
}
```

Form Hidden fields

```html
<%= hidden_field_tag "deleted_product_ids[]", "", id: "deleted_product_ids" %>
<%= hidden_field_tag "deleted_service_ids[]", "", id: "deleted_service_ids" %>
```

Now I am getting params as one product id, one service id. How can I pass ids as an array if I delete more than one product and service? How can I pass values of products and services as an array to hidden field?

Comment: I can't get what u mean. You want to have a button massively delete rows and pass all those rolls' data for sth else?

Comment: @ MatrixTai  i want to pass product and service ids as an array on click, now onclick it is passing only one product and service id.

Comment: see now it is passing like this 'Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Uvuezyw1izPomzf5LSfgbov7AjB5Q0kofmto7AZ9xlVco1C7HQ7LYNxJxSyNUP0sBd4gtGEmDI1aAgOZBqKkBg==",  "deleted_product_ids"=>"2", "deleted_service_ids"=>"2", "commit"=>"Next", "id"=>"2"}'

Comment: But i want to pass params like this, deleted_product_ids"=>"1,3", deleted_service_ids"=>"2,4"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get what you mean correctly,

```
function deleteRow(id,type) {
  var operation_type = type;

  if (operation_type == "Service") {
    var org_value = $('#deleted_service_ids').val()
    var sav = org_value ? org_value  + ',' + id : id;
    $('#deleted_service_ids').val(sav);
  } else {
    var org_value = $('#deleted_product_ids').val()
    var sav = org_value ? org_value  + ',' + id : id;
    $('#deleted_product_ids').val(sav);
  }
}
```